# how to dynamc import img

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, dynamic-import

I try to change dynamically the img for a react hangman project. So I tried with a state but an error occured saying `Cannot convert object to primitive value`

So I've tried to passed directly the function that import dynamically to my img but that makes an infinite loop.

This is the function

```
loadHangmanSvg() {
  const { attempts } = this.state
  const svgName = `hangman_${attempts}`
  import(`./assets/${svgName}.svg`).then(svgName => {
    this.setState({
      svgName
    });
  });
};
```

and this is the prop

```
svgHangman={this.loadHangmanSvg()}
```

**Thanks for your help :D**

Comment: You shouldn't use  `this.loadHangmanSvg()` in the `render` method of your react component. When you try `this.setState()`, the component will rerender and `this.loadHangmanSvg()` will excute again which will make an infinite loop.

Comment: Would you like to clarify reasons to use dynamic import? what goal do you want to achieve? According to naming `hangman_${attempts}` I may suggest that you would to load different hangman images to display how many attempt was made. It does not look effective, maybe dynamically changing fragments visibility on once loaded svg will be more preferable?

Comment: Right, I want to display the right svg depending the number of attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loadHangmanSvg() {
  const { attempts } = this.state
  const svgName = `hangman_${attempts}`
  import(`./assets/${svgName}.svg`).then(svgName => {
    // only when svgName is undefined, change the state of component
    if (!this.state.svgName) {
        this.setState({
            svgName
        });
    }
  });
};
```